# What's the best alternative to nested IF statements in this example?

Tags: worksheet-function

What would be a better way (easier to read and maintain & less resource-intensive) way to do what I need instead of nested if statements?
[image]

The formulas in the right 4 columns are all the same, they just refer to different parts of different tabs, which all work exactly the same way. The Initial Email Sent column is chosen by the user (data validation). The highlighted formula is:

```
 =IF(OR([Initial Email Sent]="on hold",[Initial Email Sent]="not applicable"),[@[Initial Email
 Sent]],IF(COUNTIF(a414engagement[Status],"<>Not Applicable")=0,"Not
 Applicable",(IF((COUNTIF(a414engagement[Status],"Not
 Started")+(COUNTIF(a414engagement[Status],"In
 Progress"))=0),"Completed",(IF(COUNTIF(a414engagement[Status],"In
 Progress")+(COUNTIF(a414engagement[Status],"Completed"))>0,"In
 Progress","Not Started"))))))
```

A bit of a mouthful. It refers to part of the A414 tab, which looks like this:
[image]

The purpose of the formula:

1. If Initial Email Sent on this row is *not applicable* this cell should say *not applicable*.
2. If Initial Email Sent is *on hold* this cell should say *on hold*

The other functions all relate to what's on the target worksheet, not the overview worksheet:

3. If all of the elements are marked *not started*, the A414 cell in the overview should say *not started*
4. If all the elements are marked *completed*, the overview cell should say *completed*.
5. In any other combination, (e.g. all *in progress*, half *completed* & half *not started*) the overview cell should say *in progress*.

Answer (score 1):

Your formula doesn't fully cover your description. Here is a formula for the scenario you've described:

`=IF( OR( [Initial Email Sent]="on hold", [Initial Email Sent]="not applicable" ), [@[Initial Email Sent]], IF( COUNTIF( a414engagement[Status], "<>Not Started" )=0, "Not Started", IF( COUNTIF( a414engagement[Status], "<>Completed" )=0, "Completed", "In progress" ) ) )`

Or maybe easier understandable:

```
=IF(
    OR(
        [Initial Email Sent]="on hold",
        [Initial Email Sent]="not applicable"
    ),
    [@[Initial Email Sent]],
    IF(
        COUNTIF(
            a414engagement[Status],
            "<>Not Started"
        )=0,
        "Not Started",
        IF(
            COUNTIF(
                a414engagement[Status],
                "<>Completed"
            )=0,
            "Completed",
            "In progress"
        )
    )
)
```

The trick here is instead of counting all which are "not started" you look for 0 occurrences where cell is not "not started".

Comment: +1, this is much tidier (and more correct) than what I did. It still uses nested ifs, though

Comment: Yes, there are still IFs. Unfortunately there is no function in Excel which could replace it.